# In gsm modems, how to inform when a new message has been received (Interruptly) using at commands like CNMA or CNMI?

Tags: sms, serial-port, gsm, at-command

I'm developing a winform program in which, I need send and receiving SMS messages, I have no problem in sending SMS, but i don't know how to inform when a new message has been received in a gsm modem? I wanna have an acknowledgement like an interrupt or event, when a new message has been received. As far as I know i should work to at+CNMI or at+CNMA, but unfortunately i cant find an example for those.Furthermore I wanna know how to get delivery message or how to handle that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to inform via interrupt when a new message has been received, using AT-Commands +CNMA or +CNMI in GSM Modems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775672/how-to-inform-via-interrupt-when-a-new-message-has-been-received-using-at-comma)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on device type you are using. Use AT+CNMI=? to see all possible options your device supports.