# How to inform via interrupt when a new message has been received, using AT-Commands +CNMA or +CNMI in GSM Modems?

Tags: winforms, sms, serial-port, gsm, at-command

I'm developing a winform program in which I need to send and receive SMS messages.

I have no problem sending SMS, but I don't know how to inform when a new message has been received via a GSM modem. I want to have an acknowledgement like an interrupt or event, when a new message has been received.

As far as I know I should work to `at+CNMI` or `at+CNMA`, but unfortunately I can't find an example or suitable reference for those. Furthermore, I need to know how to get delivery message or how to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AT+CNMI and AT+CNMA are standard AT commands defined in the spec 3GPP TS 27.005, available [here.](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm)

For confirmation of successful delivery, see section 3.5.1 of this document which is the description for  "Send message, +CMGS".

Answer (score 3):

When you are defining new port in your connection to connect, you should get a data received trigger to it.

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
//...
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
```

and in that trigger:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
     MessageBox.Show(sp.ReadExisting()); //Data received
}
```